# Is there a way to extract only specific lines from a text file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a big text file that has around 200K lines of records/lines.

But I need to extract only specific lines which Start with CLM. For example, if the file has 100K lines that start with CLM I should print all that 100K lines alone.

Can anyone help me to achieve this using python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple ways to achieve this.

1. you can simply iterate through the lines and search for a pattern using the `re` library

   ### Solution 1

   ```
   # Note :- Regex is faster in terms of execution as compared to string match
   import re
   pattern = re.compile("CLM")

   for line in open("sample.txt"):
       for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
           print(line)
   ```
2. If you want you can also run the bash command inside the python script.

   ### Solution 2

   There are two popular modules to use:- `os` and `subprocess`

   `os` is kind of deprecated, I would recommend using the `subprocess` module as below:-

   Below is the code to print the output on the console: -

   ```
   import subprocess
   process = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-i', '^hel*', 'sample.txt'],
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
   stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
   print(stdout)
   ```

   In the above, we are passing the argument `universal_newlines=True` because the output (stdout) is of type bytes.

   In the above `grep` command I have passes `-i` argument to ignore case sensitivity. If you want only to search for `CLM` and not `clm`, remove that and use it

   I have used the `grep` command to depict the use case, you can also use `awk` or `sed` or any command as per your requirement.

Just an addon, if you want to save the output in some file, let's say `ouput.txt` you can achieve this as below:-

```
import subprocess
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    process = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-i', '^hel*', 'file.txt'], stdout=f)
```

If your file is extremely large, you can also do a `poll` and check for the subprocess execution status. Refer to the below link for more details on that.

[Python-Shell-Commands](https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('CLM'):
            print(line.rstrip())
```